# Modify Web.Config Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have a function in a script that I run to make some changes to a web.config file in Azure on one of our subscriptions. It modifies an endpoint address based on searching for keywords. It works fine. I need to add into it to also modify the another key in the web.config but not 100% sure how I will add it to this function. Here is the function code:

```
function Update-ServiceConfigFile() {

    Write-Verbose "Updating Service Web Config"
    $webConfig = 'directoryToConfigInAzure/web.config'

    Write-Verbose -Message "Downloading $webConfig"
    $tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    Write-Verbose "Write $tempFile"
    Download-File $accessToken $webappName $webConfig $tempFile
    $doc = [xml](Get-Content $tempFile)

    $customerId = $WebAppName.Substring(0, 6)
    $nodes = $doc.configuration.'system.serviceModel'.client.endpoint

    foreach($node in $nodes) {
        $address = $node.Attributes['address'].Value;


        $address = $address -replace ':ServicePortNumber', ''
        $ub = [System.UriBuilder]::new($address);

        if($Insecure) {
            Write-Verbose "Setting HTTP (insecure) API endpoint"
            $ub.Scheme = 'http';
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "Setting HTTPS (secure) API endpoint"
            $ub.Scheme = 'https';
        }

        if($address.contains("SomeAddress"))
        {
           $ub.Host = "service-prod-$($customerId).ourdomainname.cloud"

        }else{
        $ub.Host = "service-$($customerId).ourdomnaineame.cloud";
        }

        if($webAppName -like '*-test') {
            $ub.Host = "service-test-$($customerId).ourdomnaineame.cloud";
        }

        $ub.Port = -1;
        $node.Attributes['address'].Value = $ub.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    $doc.Save($tempFile)

    Upload-File $accessToken $webappName $webConfig $tempFile
    Remove-Item $tempFile -Force
}
```

What I need to add in is to change another value in the system.serviceModel security mode from "none" to "transport"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the security mode for all binding nodes with code like this. It will work even if you have multiple binding nodes and different kind of binding nodes (like wsHttpBinding, basicHttpBinding etc.)

```
$bindingNodes = $doc.configuration.'system.serviceModel'.bindings

$securityNodes = $bindingNodes.SelectNodes("//security")

foreach($securityNode in $securityNodes)
{
  $mode = $securityNode.Attributes['mode'].Value;
  Write-Host("Mode = ", $mode)

  # I am checking for none in a case insensitive way here, so only none will be changed to transport. You can remove the if condition, in case you want any value to change to Transport.
  if($mode -ieq 'none') {
    $securityNode.Attributes['mode'].Value = 'Transport'
  }
}
```

I have given only the important part above for your understanding.

Overall function code would change to something like this..

```
function Update-ServiceConfigFile() {

    Write-Verbose "Updating Service Web Config"
    $webConfig = 'directoryToConfigInAzure/web.config'

    Write-Verbose -Message "Downloading $webConfig"
    $tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    Write-Verbose "Write $tempFile"
    Download-File $accessToken $webappName $webConfig $tempFile
    $doc = [xml](Get-Content $tempFile)

    $customerId = $WebAppName.Substring(0, 6)
    $nodes = $doc.configuration.'system.serviceModel'.client.endpoint

    foreach($node in $nodes) {
        $address = $node.Attributes['address'].Value;


        $address = $address -replace ':ServicePortNumber', ''
        $ub = [System.UriBuilder]::new($address);

        if($Insecure) {
            Write-Verbose "Setting HTTP (insecure) API endpoint"
            $ub.Scheme = 'http';
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "Setting HTTPS (secure) API endpoint"
            $ub.Scheme = 'https';
        }

        if($address.contains("SomeAddress"))
        {
           $ub.Host = "service-prod-$($customerId).ourdomainname.cloud"

        }else{
        $ub.Host = "service-$($customerId).ourdomnaineame.cloud";
        }

        if($webAppName -like '*-test') {
            $ub.Host = "service-test-$($customerId).ourdomnaineame.cloud";
        }

        $ub.Port = -1;
        $node.Attributes['address'].Value = $ub.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    # NEW CODE STARTS HERE

    $bindingNodes = $doc.configuration.'system.serviceModel'.bindings

    $securityNodes = $bindingNodes.SelectNodes("//security")

    foreach($securityNode in $securityNodes)
    {
      $mode = $securityNode.Attributes['mode'].Value;
      Write-Host("Mode = ", $mode)

      # I am checking for none in a case insensitive way here, so only none will be changed to transport. You can remove the if condition, in case you want any value to change to Transport.
      if($mode -ieq 'none') {
        $securityNode.Attributes['mode'].Value = 'Transport'
      }
    }

    # NEW CODE ENDS HERE

    $doc.Save($tempFile)

    Upload-File $accessToken $webappName $webConfig $tempFile
    Remove-Item $tempFile -Force
}
```

Comment: thank you - that looks pretty good! I was actually just about to write a separate function because I hadn't received any responses; but this looks pretty good. I am going to test and if all goes well, I will mark as correct! Thank you again!

Comment: Hello! I got an error when running the script: [error]The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

Comment: ok, can you share the config file that you're testing this script against? that way I can check further and respond

Comment: I did that in the original post, there is a picture of the config. Will that work?

Comment: That’s a very small excerpt.. My guess is it’s an issue somewhere else.. so if you can.. share the whole thing preferably as text and hide any sensitive information like url etc.

Comment: Hello, sorry I was not able too. Unfortunately, I am not able to upload the web.config file here, there is just way too much to hide for obvious reasons. But perhaps we can do this another way, can you possible help with just creating a function on its own to modify the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. You can also limit it by sharing only <system.serviceModel> tag and it's contents, simply as text in your question. I would guess, that will be limited text and not too sensitive. I'll separate out the function and edit my answer.

Comment: I actually got the original function to work! Haha, sorry! But I did notice an issue with it, in there you have `Write-Host("Mode = ", $mode)` but the comma was throwing an error so I just commented out that line as its just a write host command. I think if it were a + it would work; I will test that later but overall the function worked! Thank you!

Comment: ok got it. That same Write-Host does work for me with a , as well. In any case, that's irrelevant. Glad that the actual logic worked out :)

Comment: Interesting, not sure why it doesn't work for me. It might be because I am running this through VSTS? The error I was getting was `The function or command was called as if it were a method. Parameters should be separated by spaces.`